# How to disable reliable session in netNamedPipeBinding in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, netnamedpipebinding

How do I disable reliable sessions in a named pipe binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named Pipe doesn't support reliable session configuration. You'd need to create a custom binding.

More info at [Reliable Sessions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136.aspx)

Comment: Named pipes are ALWAYS support reliable sessions.

Comment: Correct, and that's why i said you can't configure it

Answer (score 0):

Before opening the host, set the `Contract.SessionMode` to `SessionMode.Allowed` when using a named pipe binding

```
// create a service host with a custom endpoint based on what we know
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceHostType);
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractName, binding, endpoint.Uri);
ep.Contract.SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed;

wcfServices.Add(host);
host.Open();
```